# WPF/XAML/C# Setting a Boolean variable on MouseOver

Tags: wpf, xaml, mouseover

If I have a **boolean** variable in a **ViewModel** Class, lets say

`public bool test = true;` (This is in C#)

Is there ANYWAY in XAML/Expression Blend to take this variable and change it to 
false USING PURELY XAML, no code behind or anything?

I want to do this for a mouse over event.
If the mouse is over a certain object the boolean variable should become false, otherwise it should remain true.

Comment: Normally you handle this in your ViewModel to make data binding easier. 

If you don't want to flip the bool in your ViewModel you can write a custom control that has a MouseOver property that works the way you like it. Clients using this control will not require any code behind then since handled in control. 

Another alternative is to use a ValueConverter in your binding that flips a bool value.

Comment: Why does your ViewModel want to know if the mouse is over a control used to display a part of it?

Answer (score 0):

**Answer 1 (easiest):**

Why not do this?

```
public bool Test
{
    get { return myControl.IsMouseOver; }
}
```

I know you want to do it in all XAML, but since you're already declaring the property, you might as well do this instead of saying.

```
public bool Test = false;
```

**Answer 2 (more code, MVVM approach which is better in the long run):**

Here basically, you create a Dependency Property (called Test) on Window1, and on the XAML side, you create a style for Window1 that says that its Test property will be the same as the button IsMouseOver property (I left the myButton_MouseEnter event so you can check the state of the variable when the mouse is over the button, I checked myself and it does change to true, you can remove the MouseEnter handler, and it'll still work)

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="StackOverflowTests.Window1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="Window1" x:Name="window1" Height="300" Width="300"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:StackOverflowTests">
    <Window.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type local:Window1}">
            <Setter Property="Test" Value="{Binding ElementName=myButton, Path=IsMouseOver}">
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <Button x:Name="myButton" Height="100" Width="100" MouseEnter="myButton_MouseEnter">
            Hover over me
        </Button>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

C#:

```
public partial class Window1 : Window
    {
        public Window1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public bool Test
        {
            get { return (bool)GetValue(TestProperty); }
            set { SetValue(TestProperty, value); }
        }

        // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for Test.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
        public static readonly DependencyProperty TestProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("Test", typeof(bool), typeof(Window1), new UIPropertyMetadata(false));

        private void myButton_MouseEnter(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            bool check = this.Test;
        }
    }
```